# Google spreadsheet: use value as row number

Tags: google-sheets

I have a return value from a function in cell `A1`. Let's say it's `51`.
How can I use this value as a row number. I don't want `51` in `A1` but instead I want the value from cell `A51` in cell `A1`.
Is there a formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use indirect:

```
= indirect ("A"& 51)
```