# Use the number in a cell to establish how big my range in my function will be

Tags: google-sheets

I have a function in my Google Sheet which looks like this:

```
=sort(bk_01!A2:F539,row(bk_01!A2:F539),)
```

I have a cell (`O1`), that has a number, which I'd like to use in this function, instead of hardcoding it. (Basically replace the `539` with what ever is in cell `O1`). How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google spreadsheet: use value as row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063613/google-spreadsheet-use-value-as-row-number)

Answer (score 0):

```
sort(bk_01!A2:INDEX(F:F,O1)...
```